# Server-side processing DataTable

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, datatables

Can you please provide me an example on how to use server side pagination using Spring MVC.

In my script I have.

```
oTable = $('#example2').dataTable({
"bJQueryUI": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"aLengthMenu":[10,20,40,60,80,100],
'iDisplayLength': 10,
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
'sAjaxSource': 'test?firstDate=${firstDate}&secondDate=${secondDate}',

});
$( ".DataTables_sort_icon " ).css( "float" , "right");
```

Comment: See this example [integrate DataTables within a Spring MVC application](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/29550/server-side-processing-with-spring-mvc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working DataTables server side processing, first confirm which version of the DataTables js included in your projec because there is a variation while initialization dataTable object for 1.9.x and 1.10.x.

if you are using DataTable 1.10.x version then here is full doc for doing sever side data processing using bootstrap dataTable js. follow the link

https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html